# Visual studio 2015 code not working on Visual Studio code IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have an issue that I've been trying to google and search for many days now and I just can't seem to get it to work. So I'm trying to get Visual Studio Code to work and it works fine to some degree.
This is the code I used in Visual Studio 2015:

```
        var client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress,
                                               fromPassword)
        };
```

So the issue is that I get an error **"The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.0]"**
and
**"The name 'SmtpDeliveryMethod' does not exist in the current context [netcoreapp1.0]"**
And yes I've installed **nuget** and I did install all the libraries I need which is System.Net.Mail and the latest version and it just doesn't work and I have no clue why. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Net.Mail;` in the header

Comment: Yep  i do everything works fine in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Net.Mail and its SmtpClient are not yet supported in a .NET Core 1.0/1.1 app.

Looks like it is scheduled for .NET Core 2.0
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1006

You can use MailKit for now:
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

or maybe SendGrid
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full reference. It seems that the compiler is not finding the reference to that library:

```
var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
```

Comment: look at this article: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/how-to-send-emails-in-asp-net-core-1-0